# output string overwrite last string on terminal in Linux with c++

Tags: c++, linux, ncurses, iomanip

Say I have a command line program. Is there a way so that when I say

```
std::cout << stuff
```

if I don't do a `std::cout << '\n'` in between another `std::cout << stuff`, another output of stuff will overwrite the last stuff on the same line (cleaning the line) starting at the leftmost column?

I think [ncurses](/questions/tagged/ncurses) has the ability to do this? If possible, it would be great if I could say `std::cout << std::overwrite << stuff`

Where `std::overwrite` is some sort of iomanip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried carriage returns `\r`? This should do what you want.

Comment: Don't forget to include an `std::flush` after the `\r`, otherwise you might write lots of "stuff" that doesn't appear for a long time because the iostream is caching it. (e.g. `std::cout << stuff << '\r' << std::flush;`)

Answer (score 1):

Also it is worth to see the escape character documentation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

You can do much more than setting carret back to the line beggining position!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to overwrite the last stuff printed and other on the same line kept intact, then you can do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string OverWrite(int x) {
    std::string s="";
    for(int i=0;i<x;i++){s+="\b \b";}
    return s;}

int main(){   
    std::cout<<"Lot's of ";
    std::cout<<"stuff"<<OverWrite(5)<<"new_stuff";  //5 is the length of "stuff"
    return(0);
}
```

Output:

```
Lot's of new_stuff
```

The OverWrite() function cleans the previous "stuff" and places the cursor at it's start.

> If you want the whole line to be cleaned and print new_stuff in that
>   place then just make the argument of `OverWrite()` big enough like
>   `OverWrite(100)` or something like that to clean the whole line
>   altogether.

And if you don't want to clean anything, just replace from the start then you can simply do this:

```
#include<iostream>

#define overwrite "\r"

int main(){ 
    std::cout<<"stuff"<<overwrite<<"new_stuff";
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Mind to explain your solution?

Comment: Thumbs up! Perfect explanation, elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a `std::istream::sentry`? You could try something like the following, which would "audit" your input.

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, std::string& input) {
    std::istream::sentry s(is);
    if(s) {
        // use a temporary string to append the characters to so that
        // if a `\n` isn't in the input the string is not read
        std::string tmp;
        while(is.good()) {
            char c = is.get();
            if(c == '\n') {
                is.getloc();
                // if a '\n' is found the data is appended to the string
                input += tmp;
                break;
            } else {
                is.getloc();
                tmp += c;
            }
        }
    }
    return(is);
}
```

The key part being that we append the characters input to the stream to a temporary variable, and if a '\n' isn't read, the data is chucked.

Usage:

```
int main() {
    std::stringstream bad("this has no return");
    std::string test;
    bad >> test;
    std::cout << test << std::endl; // will not output data
    std::stringstream good("this does have a return\n");
    good >> test;
    std::cout << test << std::endl;
```

}

This won't be quite as easy as an `iomanip`, but I hope it helps.